# Mocking read/write functions and receive warnings of redundant redeclaration

Tags: c++, mocking

I use gtest and gmock for my unit tests, I mock `unistd` read/write functions for input, sending and receiving testing([C function Gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989040/can-gmock-be-used-for-stubbing-c-functions)):

```
class MockSysFuncs {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD3(read, ssize_t(int, char*, size_t));
  MOCK_METHOD3(write, ssize_t(int, const char*, size_t));
  sem_t readSem;
  static std::shared_ptr<MockSysFuncs> _mockSysFuncObj;
};

ssize_t read(int __fd, void* __buf, size_t __nbytes);
ssize_t write(int __fd, const void* __buf, size_t __n);
```

Functions implementation (in the mock cpp file):

```
ssize_t read(int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __nbytes) {
  sem_wait(&MockSysFuncs::_mockSysFuncObj->readSem);
  return MockSysFuncs::_mockSysFuncObj->read(__fd, static_cast<char *>(__buf), __nbytes);
}

ssize_t write(int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) {
  return MockSysFuncs::_mockSysFuncObj->write(__fd, static_cast<const char *>(__buf), __n);
}
```

On compilation, I receive this warnings:

```
warning: redundant redeclaration of 'ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)' in same scope [-Wredundant-decls]
  168 | ssize_t read(int __fd, void* __buf, size_t __nbytes);
  /usr/include/unistd.h:360:16: note: previous declaration of 'ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)'
  360 | extern ssize_t read (int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __nbytes) __wur;

warning: redundant redeclaration of 'ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)' in same scope [-Wredundant-decls]
  169 | ssize_t write(int __fd, const void* __buf, size_t __n);
  /usr/include/unistd.h:366:16: note: previous declaration of 'ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)'
  366 | extern ssize_t write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) __wur;
```

Is there a way to solve this warnings without removing the `-Wredundant-decls` compilation flag?

Comment: Remove the duplicate declarations?

Comment: @Jarod42, The duplicate declaration is in ```unistd.h``` I cannot touch this file and I need to include it for other purposes except read/write.

Comment: Remove the ones you add after class `class MockSysFuncs`.

Comment: This is the mock for the read/write functions, if I remove this declaration I remove the mock.
This is how I mock C functions with gmock which is cpp tool.

Comment: As I understand, you redefine C-functions with your own version (which is UB but supported by some compileras gcc with weak symbol), but warning is about your **declarations** in header.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, you are right, the double declaration is unneeded. The tests can reach the Mock implementation without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your warning is about redundant **declarations**, so just remove them:

```
#include <unistd.h> // declare read/write

class MockSysFuncs
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD3(read, ssize_t(int, char*, size_t));
  MOCK_METHOD3(write, ssize_t(int, const char*, size_t));
  sem_t readSem;
  static std::shared_ptr<MockSysFuncs> _mockSysFuncObj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found for now is to use `#pragma`:

```
class MockSysFuncs {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD3(read, ssize_t(int, char*, size_t));
  MOCK_METHOD3(write, ssize_t(int, const char*, size_t));
  sem_t readSem;
  static std::shared_ptr<MockSysFuncs> _mockSysFuncObj;
};

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wredundant-decls"
ssize_t read(int __fd, void* __buf, size_t __nbytes);
ssize_t write(int __fd, const void* __buf, size_t __n);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

In general, I find `#pragma` as bad practice and try to avoid using it in my code but since this is mock file for unit tests and not operational code I guess it fine.