# Mock only some functions of a C static library with GMock

Tags: c, googletest, googlemock

Given a C library (`liblegacy.a`) that contains:

```c
function_legacy1()
function_legacy2()
function_legacy3()
...
function_legacy500()
```

and a C binary (`mybin`) which links against `liblegacy.a`:

```c
function_binary1() {
  function_legacy1();
  function_legacy2();
  function_legacy3();
}

function_binary200() {
  function_legacy500();
}
```

and `mybin` is *partially* tested with Google Test framework (in progress).

The technical debt is high and it will be a big work to test `mybin` and/or `liblegacy.a`.

As a step to remove this debt, I like to start implementing a test for `function_binary1` without impacting the rest. My idea would be to mock only the 3 functions used by it (`function_legacy1`, `function_legacy2`, `function_legacy3`) and keep linking against the lib so that I don't have to split the .c/.h files to have only the interesting part in the translation unit.

A first approach would probably to make a dynamic shared library that contains the 3 functions, and use LD_PRELOAD to override these ones at runtime.

Since I'm new with GMock, maybe we can do that in a better way directly with this framework.
Is is possible to mock only some functions of an external lib with GMock to avoid refactoring in this case?

Note: This question is somehow related to, but answers are not very clear to me

[Can gmock be used for stubbing C functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989040/can-gmock-be-used-for-stubbing-c-functions)

Comment: You don't need a dynamic shared library with mock implementations. Use these mock functions as a module and link it before the library. Because their references are resolved when the linker scans the library, it will not include the library's implementation. -- GoogleMock works best with C++ classes and virtual methods. It a kind of abuse to use it for C code. ;-) There might be more appropriate frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You might run into problems if you are working with a static library
(`liblegacy.a`) and a shared library `libmock.so` (`libmock.dylib` on
macOS) and if any of the mocked functions is defined in an object file
that also contains an unmocked function.

For example, if you mock `function_legacy1()` but in `liblegacy.a` it is
defined in the same object file as `function_legacy2()`, you might run
into linking conflicts with `function_legacy1()` being multiply defined,
or you might run into the wrong code being executed at runtime.

Consider the following setup:

- `legacy.h` — declares the legacy functions.
- `legacy_1_2.c` — defines `function_legacy1()` and `function_legacy2()`.
- `legacy_3_4.c` — defines `function_legacy3()` and `function_legacy4()`.
- `mock_1.c` — defines `function_legacy1()`.
- `mock_2.c` — defines `function_legacy2()`.
- `testprog1.c` — defines a `main()` function that calls each of the legacy functions.
- `testprog2.c` — a copy of `testprog1.c`.

Each of the legacy functions in each source file is the same apart from the name:

```c
void function_legacy1(void)
{
    printf("%s:%d:%s()\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
}
```

The `main()` program looks like:

```c
#include "legacy.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s:%d:%s()\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
    function_legacy1();
    function_legacy2();
    function_legacy3();
    function_legacy4();
    printf("%s:%d:%s()\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
    return 0;
}
```

The code can be compiled and run as shown below:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libmock1.dylib mock_1.c
$ gcc -shared -o libmock2.dylib mock_1.c mock_2.c
$ gcc -o testprog1 testprog1.c -L. -lmock1 -llegacy
$ gcc -o testprog2 testprog2.c -L. -lmock2 -llegacy
$ testprog1
testprog1.c:6:main()
legacy_1_2.c:6:function_legacy1()
legacy_1_2.c:11:function_legacy2()
legacy_3_4.c:6:function_legacy3()
legacy_3_4.c:11:function_legacy4()
testprog1.c:11:main()
$ testprog2
testprog2.c:6:main()
mock_1.c:6:function_legacy1()
mock_2.c:6:function_legacy2()
legacy_3_4.c:6:function_legacy3()
legacy_3_4.c:11:function_legacy4()
testprog2.c:11:main()
$
```

As you can see, there are no problems linking.
However, `testprog1` is linked with a mock library that only includes a
mock for `function_legacy1()`, and it doesn't see the mocked version of
`function_legacy1()`.
By contrast, `testprog2` is linked with a mock library that includes a
mock for `function_legacy1()` and `function_legacy2()` and it does see
both the mocked functions.

YMMV on a Linux system, or other non-macOS systems.

Thus, your mocking may or may not work if the legacy functions are defined
several per object file in the static library.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to conditionally delegate some functions to the real implementation (`function_legacy1`, `function_legacy2`, `function_legacy3`) and the rest to the mock.

I think you should be able to use [this recipe](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#delegating-calls-to-a-real-object).

For mocking stand-alone functions such as `function_legacy1`, you probably need to [wrap them](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#mocking-free-functions) inside a virtual class first. Something like this:

```
class LegacyInterface {
 public:
  ...
  virtual bool function_legacy1(int p) = 0;
  virtual bool function_legacy2(int p) = 0;
  ...
  virtual bool function_legacyn(int p) = 0;
};

// This should be used in production.
class LegacyProduction : public LegacyInterface {
 public:
  
  bool function_legacy1(int p) override {
     return ::function_legacy1(p); // Calling the real function_legacy1
  }
  bool function_legacy2(int p) override {
     return ::function_legacy2(p); // Calling the real function_legacy2
  }
  ...
  bool function_legacyn(int p) override {
     return ::function_legacyn(p); // Calling the real function_legacyn
  }
};

// This should be used in test.
class LegacyMock : public LegacyInterface {
 public:
  // Normal mock method definitions using gMock.
  MOCK_METHOD(bool, function_legacy1, (int p), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(bool, function_legacy2, (int p), (override));
  ...
  MOCK_METHOD(bool, function_legacyn, (int p), (override));

  // Delegates the default actions of function_legacy500 to the real implementation.
  void Delegate500ToReal() {
    ON_CALL(*this, function_legacy500).WillByDefault([this](int n) {
      return ::function_legacy500(n); // Calling the real function_legacy500
    });
  }
};
```

Now you should change your code to use the wrapper class:

```
function_binary1(LegacyInterface *legacy_wrapper) {
  legacy_wrapper->function_legacy1();
  legacy_wrapper->function_legacy2();
  legacy_wrapper->function_legacy3();
}

function_binary200(LegacyInterface *legacy_wrapper) {
  legacy_wrapper->function_legacy500();
}
```

where you initialize legacy_wrapper for test:

```
LegacyInterface *legacy_wrapper = new LegacyMock;
```

And for production:

```
LegacyInterface *legacy_wrapper = new LegacyProduction;
```

So your test would be:

```
TEST(LegacyTest, function_binary1) {
  LegacyMock legacy_wrapper;
  
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, function_binary1(_));
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, function_binary2(_));
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, function_binary3(_));

  // Assert
  EXPECT_EQ(function_binary1(&legacy_wrapper), ...);
}

TEST(LegacyTest, function_binary200) {
  LegacyMock legacy_wrapper;

  legacy_wrapper.Delegate500ToReal();

  // No action specified, meaning to use the default action, which is calling the real function_legacy500.
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, function_legacy500(_));

  // Assert
  EXPECT_EQ(function_binary200(), ...);
}
```

The above code can still be linked against the legacy lib as was before.